# How I can get access to API in the global command file?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

I want to create a global command in the nightwatch.js framework when I do that in page object_file without global  command function

```js
navigateWithNav() {
            return navigateWithNavToolbar.call(this, "#home-nav")
        },
```

Everything works correctly. But when I trying change function in the object _file, on global command I will get undefined for `this.api`, how I can resolve it?

```js
// page_oject file
        navigateWithNav() {
            return this.navigateWithNavToolbar("#home-nav") 
        },


// global command file

const { client } = require("nightwatch-cucumber")

const { MID_TIMEOUT } = global.config.timeouts

exports.command = async function navigateWithNavToolbar(selector) {
    return this.api.url(async (url) => {
        // if we are someplace which doesnt have the nav toolbar, then
        // goto the homepage
        if (!url.value.includes(client.launch_url)){
            await client.url(client.launch_url)
        }
        await this.api.waitForElementPresent(selector, MID_TIMEOUT, false)
        await this.api.click(selector)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the syntax that the page_oject file code is in, but you want to do something like this to bind `this`:

```
navigateWithNav = () => this.navigateWithNavToolbar("#home-nav")
```

Comment: `console.log(this.api)` in `navigateWithNav()`, before you return `this.navigateWithNavToolbar("#home-nav") `. That will let you know if the problem is this binding.